# TestLink - DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START (CWE-200)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench, testlink

I installed MySQL Workbench 6.3, you can install TestLink (php) on the ISS , managed to install the tools , but when I access the site has the following message on the home page , I already researched in several places and found the solution .

Windows 7 + IIS + PHP 5.6

> DB Access Error - debug_print_backtrace() OUTPUT START   ATTENTION:
>   Enabling more debug info will produce path disclosure weakness
>   (CWE-200) 
>               Having this additional Information could be useful for reporting 
>               issue to development TEAM.

Comment: Have you enabled the configuration to get more details and post here?

Comment: Why are you here if you found the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/var/testlink/logs/userlog<num>.log` you can see something like:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation users - in /var/www/testlink-copy/third_party/adodb/drivers/adodb-postgres7.inc.php - Line 167
```

To resolve this problem you must set rights to each relation or sequence from the log file.

For example (`db_version` table):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on table db_version to testlink;
```